# pg_restore out of shared memory error on big db restore

Tags: linux, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to restore PostgreSQL using following command on **linux machine**.

```
pg_restore --verbose -d DB_NAME dump_file.pg
```

This is importing the DB at the middle it throw following error.

```
pg_restore: ERROR:  out of shared memory
```

This is a little big DB with more than 300 tables. Is this issue caused by lack of RAM or hard disk space? And is there any way to segment and import the DB to avoid the error situation?

Following is the export command which i use.

```
pg_dump -Fc -f dump_file.pg DB_NAME
```

Comment: Are you restoring inside an empty database or a pre-existing database with some or all tables and foreign keys already in place?

Comment: At a guess you're running into issues with too many locks. It's a bit odd. Can you set `log_error_verbosity = verbose` in `postgresql.conf`, restart PostgreSQL, and re-run, then show what the error from the log file is? Also, exact version? What's your `max_locks_per_transaction`, `shared_buffers`, `max_connections` and `max_pred_locks_per_transaction` set to in `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: @Daniel : I'm importing into empty database.